# Xcode iPhoneでの実機テストについて

Tags: swift, xcode

Xcodeで実機テストをしたく,iPhoneをコードを使って繋げてみて左上の実行ボタンを押したらこのようなエラーが出てしまいました。よろしければ教えて頂きたいです。よろしくお願いします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: エラーメッセージなど、回答を書くための根幹となる情報は画像だけではなくテキストとしてご質問中に含めていただけないでしょうか。回答を書こうとする人間がそのテキストを使って情報を検索したり、同じ問題で苦しんでいる人がこの質問スレを見つけやすくなったりします。Xcodeに表示されるほとんどのテキスト情報はドラッグして選択すれば、コピー可能だと思います。

Comment: まずは、エラーメッセージを読んでみるとよいと思います。

Comment: 単に「エラーが出ました」で終わらせず、「エラーメッセージの内容(英文)が分からない」のか「内容は理解したうえで、どう対処すべきかが分からない」のかなどを明確にすべきかと思います。 / メッセージを読む限りは「実機の iOS バージョンを上げるか、"deployment target" を下げるように」と指示されているように見えます。

Answer (score 0):

私の場合はこの２つの記事が参考になりました。

1. [https://apprili.com/2018/09/05/the-run-destination-is-not-valid-for-running-the-scheme【xcode、ios】/](https://apprili.com/2018/09/05/the-run-destination-is-not-valid-for-running-the-scheme%E3%80%90xcode%E3%80%81ios%E3%80%91/)
2. https://pg.kdtk.net/1322

1番は下の部分のエラーメッセージが違うので、違うと思いますが、2番目のエラーメッセージが同じなのと、`おが`の横の部分に`OS version lower than deployment target`と表示されているところから、iOSのバージョンを上げるか、Xcodeのプロジェクト設定で`deployment target`を下げればOKです。

#### `deployment target`を下げる方法

[image: Deployment Target項目]

1. プロジェクトエディターを開いて、
2. プロジェクトエディターの左側 `TARGETS`の下にある`[自分のアプリ名]`を選択して、
3. `Deployment Target` という項目があるので、
4. プルダウンメニューから自分のiPhoneのOSバージョンよりも低い（または同じ）バージョンを選択します。

これで実行できるはずです。
もし実行できなかったら、ググってみましょう。